# Invoke Standalone Sonar Analysis isn't an option on Jenkins

Tags: plugins, jenkins, sonarqube

I've run into a problem on Jenkins. I have installed the SonarQube plugin for Jenkins(v 1.5.7.0 can't upgrade for project), but when I try to add the build step "Invoke Standalone Sonar Analysis" it isn't an option in the build steps. I've followed a few tutorials and I have installed every SonarQube plugin there is on Jenkins and it still isn't an option.

As far as I have seen no one else has come across this particular issue. Might it have something to do with my Jenkins version? I have seen some tutorials with similar Jenkins versions that are able to add that build step so I feel thats not the issue. Anyone else come across this?

Add build options:
[image: Build options]

[image: SonarQube plugin is installed]

Comment: anything in your Jenkins log? Also, is this on existing projects? New projects? All projects?

Comment: I don't think the log has any information on this. There just isn't an option. No build is taking place. All projects on this particular CI machine do not have it as an option.

Comment: if you can, try scrolling back in your jenkins log to when the plugin loaded (startup) to see if it says anything. Also, so all the expected global admin entries show up for this plugin?

Comment: This is my first time working with Jenkins, going up the log didn't reveal any problems when it started up. I have SonarQube runner, and options in my configure for Jenkins, I just don't have it in add build. I'm unsure what global admin entires are, or where to check for them.

Comment: Thank you for your help Miss Campbell I appreciate it. I have seen your name on a few of the articles I've read on SonarQube's website.

Comment: Did you made the setting in Jenkins -> Configure System -> SonarQube Runner -> Add SonarQube runner. It's been a while but I thought you first had to add those settings, to reveal the build step.

Comment: I did make sure to add the SonarQube runner, still didn't reveal the build step.

Comment: Have you solved this issue?
I am currently facing the same problem on Jenkins 2.32.3

Comment: @electricalbah I never resolved this issue. I did a work around by using the sonar-maven-plugin and just running the analysis through a maven build step. I like this a lot more actually since maven automatically collects source/class/test files and maintains project structure in the coverage results. Its easier to set up, and requires minimal maintenance.